# Chart.js, adding footer to chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using Chart.js 2.0. I'm looking for a way to add a footer (line of text) at the bottom of the chart in order to display sources of data.

I tried to solve it via the option object, the same way as title and legend are included and modified. Like this:

```
`options: { ... 
  footer: {
    display: true,
    text: 'data from xy'
  }
}`
```

I saw 'footer' several times mentioned in the documentation and ways to style it or use it in the context of 'tooltips', but haven't seen anything how to add it concretely.

EDIT/UPDATE:
I've found two workarounds (but no perfect solution) to add a footer to the chart while trying to solve this. In case someone is running into same problem like I did, here some suggestions how to solve this.

Nr. 1: adding a HTML element. This workaround has the disadvantage that the added HTML element is not shown if a user downloads the chart as a .png. Maybe this is the best solution, if the element doesn't have to be visible if a user downloads the chart as a .png.

```
`var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: { ... },
  options: {
   legend: { ... },
   ... 
   legendCallback: function(){
    return '<p>bla bla</p>';
   },
  ...
 },
});
document.getElementById('legendID').innerHTML = 
myChart.generateLegend();`
```

adding AFTER the canvas a div to append the new HTML element
    `<div id=legendID></div>`

Nr. 2: adding another dataset which is empty but a label which contains the information that is supposed to be displayed. borderColor and backgroundColor set to transparent. Adding some empty labels (" ") gives some distance between labels and the footer which is added. The disadvantage of this workaround are the limited possibilities for styling.

Nr. 3: the solution of ana liza. This finally works best for my case since the added info is visible on the .png.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the official [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html):

> **Labeling Axes**
>
> When creating a chart, you want to tell the viewer what data they are viewing. To do this, you need to label the axis.
>
> **The scale label configuration is nested under the scale configuration in the scaleLabel key. It defines options for the scale title. Note that this only applies to cartesian axes.**

You can add labels for both axes but in your case, since you only need it on the `x-axis`, your chart `options` should look similar to this.

```js
var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Party size',
          fontColor: '#C7C7CC',
          fontSize: 11
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: basically this works. My problem: I want to display the 'legend' at the bottom of the chart. If I add the sources as a label of the 'xAxes', the sources/label is displayed on the top of the 'legend'. This isn't perfect since the sources should be at the very bottom on the right side. - But it would more or less work if the 'legend' is not at the bottom.

Comment: Can you provide an image of how it should look like?

Comment: Ana Liza: It should look like this, I hope you get the idea. Thx! https://ibb.co/XZrBBJ4

Comment: There's no option to indicate the position for the scale label though. There might be a way to extend it and customized the behaviour but at the moment, I don't know how. The alternative way to do this is to create the scale label manually instead of putting it on the chart options. In this way, you'll have more freedom to manipulate the style but it won't be included in the canvas image though.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about adding it manually with html/css right after the canvas, but as you mentioned, it wouldn't be in the canvas image - and if someone downloads the chart as a .png the sources wouldn't be displayed in the .png. I was hoping this is possible with the 'footer' object (in case 'footer' refers to the bottom of the chart) since adding sources at the bottom of charts is very common. -  But your solution works if I do the legend on the top of the chart. Thanks again!

Comment: @digijay I will in case there will be no other solution. I still hope to solve this with the footer object.

Comment: @wenzf I think you are confusing the tooltip footer to the chart footer, The footer provided by the chart.js library is for the tooltips and can be added to the options like this `tooltips: {
      callbacks: {        
        footer: function(tooltipItem, data) { return 'Total: 100 planos.'; }
      }
    }`. Here is working example for tooltip footers -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/14/